# Can't expose influxdb api with nginx in kubernetes

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, influxdb, azure-aks

I'm trying to have InfluxDB running on Kubernetes on Azure (AKS) and exposing its HTTP API through it.
I'm using nginx ingress.
I installed everything through helm.
My problem is: I have nginx installed and exposed, but I can't get InfluxDB exposed
I've tried everything but I dont have enough knowledge with Kubernetes, so any help is appreciated!

Here's a screenschot with the services:
[image]

And Ingresses:
[image]

As you can see, no external endpoints are set to influxdb.
Any help?

thank you!

Comment: Can you post the values file you used for InfluxDB?

Comment: It looks like there are no endpoints for your ingress. If you post the YAML for your deployment, service, and ingress I might be able to help.

Comment: Here's the YAML file i used. The command was `helm install -f ./values.yaml --name influxdb stable/influxdb`
and this is the file: https://pastebin.com/4FwePYPQ
I also installed nginx using `helm install --name nginx stable/nginx` (no custom yaml)

Comment: can you provide results of `kubectl get ingress ingress_name` ?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HStA7eP.png